# Distributed clause in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Please explain me or provide a link about what **distributed by** really does in hive?
How can it control a file to being send to a particular reducer??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DISTRIBUTE BY controls how map output is divided among reducers. By default, MapReduce computes a hash on the keys output by mappers and tries to evenly distribute the key-value pairs among the available reducers using the hash values. 
Say we want the data for each value in a column to be captured together. We can use DISTRIBUTE BY to ensure that the records for each  go to the same reducer. DISTRIBUTE BY works similar to GROUP BY in the sense that it controls how reducers receive rows for processing, Note that Hive requires that the DISTRIBUTE BY clause come before the SORT BY clause if it's in same query .

Comment: if you don't use distribute by, and you are doing aggregation. MAP-REDUCE will still ensure all group by columns go to the same reducer, then why use `Distribute by` at all ?

Answer (score 3):

**DISTRIBUTE BY** is a good workaround to utilize less memory when you have a memory-intensive job, and forces Hadoop to use Reducers instead of having a Map-only job. Essentially Mappers do some grouping of the rows based on the **DISTRIBUTE BY** columns specified, which make the framework make less work overall, and pass on these aggregates to the Reducers.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Dynamic-PartitionInsert

Answer (score 0):

You can the official documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy#LanguageManualSortBy-SyntaxofClusterByandDistributeBy).